# JQuery setting Hidden Input for MVC Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwb7N/17/), it shows a listbox with  multiple select, and if you click read, it takes the selected values and puts them into `<p>` tag.

Two questions:

1) How do you modify the fiddle that I have created, so when you have finished selecting the items in the listbox it automatically puts them into the `<p>` tag? I'm guessing you go down the "on change" route.

2) How do you modify the fiddle that I have created, so it puts the array of **selected values into a hidden input** which is then **submitted back** to a MVC3 controller? Is this achievable doing it this way?

**UPDATE:**
Taking on what you guys put as answers, I thought I'd share what I managed to achieve and accomplish with your answers, the example shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkCzt/2/)

- Single select listbox
- Dynamically changing the contents of the second listbox depending on the selected item of the first listbox
- Showing what items are selected from the second box with the selected value from the first listbox at the end, and this is all put in the hidden input

Thanks guys for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your first question. It looks to me like it's doing that - can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure i can clarify any further, basically, i click an item or select multiple ones, it automatically adds the values to the p tag

Comment: What do you mean by "How do you modify it"

Comment: So what you want is just post the selected item in an array to your controller on button click.....

Comment: yeah, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tAaRR/2/

i just replaced your javascript code with below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#App_RunFromUSB').change(function () {
         if ($('#App_RunFromUSB:checked').length > 0) {
             $('#jj').show('1000');
         } else {
             $('#jj').hide('1000');
         }
     });

     $('#SelectBox').change(function () {
      var Value = '';
             var text = '' 

         $("#SelectBox option:selected").each(function () {
            Value+=$(this).val();
             text +=$(this).text();
             $("#selectedValues").append(Value + ": " + text + "<br />");
         });
      alert(text);
         $('#hidden1').val(text);

     });

 });
```

Hope this helps. if any issues let me know.

Comment: so this should effectively place all options chosen, into the hidden input, for posting back to the controller :), thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, updated your fiddle with some optimization and reduced a lot of non required code. You can take a look if you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/tkkSr/

```
$(function () {       
     var artItems = ["Art 1","Art 2","Art 3","Art 4","Art 5","Art 6"];
     var vidItems = ["Video 1","Video 2","Video 3","Video 4","Video 5","Video 6"];
     $('#SelectBox').change(function () {
         var str = "", inHTML = "",items;
         items = $(this).val() == 'art' ? artItems: vidItems;
         $.each(items,function(i,ob){
             inHTML += '<option value="'+i+'">'+ob+'</option>'
         });
         $("#SelectBox2").empty().append(inHTML);
     });

     $('#SelectBox2').change(function () {
         $("#selectedValues").text($(this).val() + ';' + $("#SelectBox").val());
         $('#hidden1').val($(this).val());
     });

 });
```

Comment: You know what, i was going to ask this as a question, "could anyone improve that code", but some people complain about those types of questions, so I'm glad you have done this for me, it is so much more than helpful!

Comment: `function(i,ob){
             inHTML += '<option value="'+i+'">'+ob+'</option>'
         }` is that what `$.each` takes as a second argument, is there any requirements for the params of the function or how many there are?

Comment: please could you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549027/jquery-adding-and-removing-items-from-listbox

Comment: @No1_Melman.. I am late to the party :). But i have provided another way of doing it. Please have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

This bit of jQuery should do.....[example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TxK4N/)

```
$("#SelectBox").change(function(){
$("#selected").empty();

$("#SelectBox option:selected").each(function(){
    $("#selected").append("<p>" + $(this).val() + " : " + $(this).html() + "</p>"); 
    });
});
```

Now, if you want to include the selected items in a hidden value and post it to your controller, you could use an AJAX call or a hidden form value.